# Using If / then javascript to redirect page "a" that shares a template with page "b"

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have two pages that use the same template, and I now need one page to redirect to the other. Problem is I only have access to the one template, but not the two pages. That means I have to set up an if/else statement in the template to do the redirect. Mind you I'm very green, but I've been trying to get the following code to do the trick... unsuccessfully.

```
var uri = location.href;

if(uri == 'http://URL-A.com')  {

} else {
    window.location = "http://URL-B.com";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare a URL to a string you first need to ensure the `document.location` is a string, rather than an object<sup>1</sup>, and then you need to quote the string against which you're comparing it:

```
var uri = document.location.href;

if(uri == "http://URL-A.com") 
    // not sure what's happening here
}
else {
    window.location="http://URL-B.com";
}
```

---

1. As noted by [Sidnicious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84745/sidnicious), in the comments, `document.location` is an object, while `document.location.href` is a string; a fact which entirely escaped me as I first wrote this answer. Since corrected.

Comment: `document.location` isn’t a string, but `document.location.href` is.

Comment: @Sidnicious: many thanks, I stand corrected and have edited that correction into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you’d do an HTTP redirect instead of using JavaScript. But if that’s not an option, here’s the problem with your example:

```
if(uri==http://URL-A.com) // Don’t do this
```

The URL should have quotes around it, to make it a string. You could also use the `!=` operator to clean the code up a little bit. And, it *is* usually best practice to say `window.location` instead of just `location` for clarity, even though they’re usually the same. You also don’t need a semicolon at the end of a block:

```
if (window.location.href != "http://URL-A.com") {
    window.location = "http://URL-B.com";
}
```

If that doesn’t work for you, something else is going on.

Comment: OK. It must be that something else is going on. I've tried each of your suggestions to no avail.

Comment: Just to be sure, I need to bookend the code above with <script type="text/javascript"> </script>, and place it in the <head> of the template, yes?

Comment: @Kent Yep, and you shouldn’t need the `type` attribute, since `text/javascript` is the default (but it won’t hurt). Hmm, if it’s not working, the next step might be to look at your browser’s error console (which browser are you testing in?) and to add a `console.log` statement or two to see what’s going on. For example, you might add an `else` statement like this: `else { console.log("location didn't match"); }`. The message would show up in the error console when the code runs successfully but the location doesn’t match.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<script>
    if (location.href !== 'http://URL-A.com') {
        location = 'http://URL-B.com';
    }
</script>
```

- You might consider using `window.location` or `document.location` depending on what you want.
- Your if/else is unnecessary since you can use a not-equal-to comparison.
- You should use `===` or `!==` to avoid type coercion.